# Plot Histogram of the sum of values for each month

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, histogram

Plot Histogram for confirmed COVID 19 Cases Dataset where date needs to be on x-axis vs confirmed covid 19 cases on y-axis

I want to plot month i.e.,FEB 2020,MAR 2020 on x-axis vs confirmed covid 19 cases on y-axis with measurement of 1e6.

Dataset :

[[image: Dataset and sample output]]

I wrote below code but I don't know how to exactly incorporate date vs confirmed covid 19 cases.

```
df_us["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_us["Date"])

df_us["Month"] = df_us["Date"].dt.to_period("M")

monthly_data = df_us.groupby(df_us["Month"])["Count"].sum()

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.hist(monthly_data, bins=20, color="blue", alpha=0.7, edgecolor='black')
plt.title("Histogram of Monthly Confirmed COVID-19 Cases (US)")
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.ylabel("Confirmed Cases")
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: A histogram is an estimate of the density of some random variable. In a histogram, the horizontal axis shows the possible values of this random variable. This plot's X axis shows _dates_. It shows how the number of cases _changed over time_. This plot is _not_ a histogram, but some kind of binned time-series plot.

Answer (score 1):

- You are plotting a bar plot of the monthly `sum` of `'new_cases'`.
- [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram): *Histograms are sometimes confused with [bar charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart). A histogram is used for [continuous data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_data), where the bins represent ranges of data, while a bar chart is a plot of [categorical variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable).*

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the data; selected columns, parse the date column and set it as the index
df = pd.read_csv('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv',
                 usecols=['location', 'date', 'new_cases'], parse_dates=['date'],
                 date_format='%Y-%m-%d', index_col='date')

# select data based on location, and only select the new_cases column
us = df.loc[df.location.eq('United States'), 'new_cases']

# calculate the monthly sum of new_cases
us_monthly = us.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()

# format the index to Year-month
us_monthly.index = us_monthly.index.strftime('%Y-%m')

# plot
ax = us_monthly.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 6), xlabel='Date', ylabel='Confirmed Cases', title='Monthly Confirmed COVID-19 Cases (US)')
```

[image]

---

### Data

#### `df`

- This is a `pandas.DataFrame`

```
               location  new_cases
date                              
2020-01-03  Afghanistan        0.0
2020-01-04  Afghanistan        0.0
2020-01-05  Afghanistan        0.0
2020-01-06  Afghanistan        0.0
2020-01-07  Afghanistan        0.0
...                         
2023-07-29  Zimbabwe           NaN
2023-07-30  Zimbabwe           0.0
2023-07-31  Zimbabwe           0.0
2023-08-01  Zimbabwe           0.0
2023-08-02  Zimbabwe           0.0
```

#### `us`

- This is a `pandas.Series`

```
date
2020-01-03    0.0
2020-01-04    0.0
2020-01-05    0.0
2020-01-06    0.0
2020-01-07    0.0
Name: new_cases, dtype: float64
```

#### `us_monthly`

- This is a `pandas.Series`

```
date
2020-01         8.0
2020-02        61.0
2020-03    173074.0
2020-04    857163.0
2020-05    755116.0
Name: new_cases, dtype: float64
```